# How to provide HA with just 2 or 3 machine in Arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I am following the documentation https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/8f79d1c187ec18e803dd095baa0ab0f9b04d38a2/Documentation/Books/Manual/Deployment/README.md for Cluster setup and it seems unless we use Mesos, DC/OS the cluster is too clumsy (requires manual binary compilation of source code). I tried setting up Apache Mesos with it's minimal configuration but the minimal configuration is very expensive !!. It costs about $1300 per month (many xlarge ec2 instances). So, that's off the hook.

Is it possible to setup HA with just config changes in arangodb setup? All I want is to run minimum 2 machine , replicate (sync or async) the data and have the client connected behind a load balancer. Is it possible. Do you have any recommendation. I found https://www.arangodb.com/2016/12/starting-arangodb-cluster-easy-way/ but it's experimental. Don't want to use experimental piece in a production enviornment.
Currently we are hosting about 40 million documents in 3 arangodb collections. and these 40 million documents are analyzed every hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with config changes only. If you want to achieve HA, you will have to setup a cluster on your 2 boxes. But let me just bring up an issue here that you should keep in mind first.

The cluster configuration, i.e. database layout, collections, sharding replication etc needs to rely on a replicated state machine; arangodb speak for that is "the agency". It is realised with the RAFT consensus protocol. RAFT and familiar replicated state machines conceptually ask for an odd number of instances or machines. So you can perfectly well install arangodb on your 2 boxes with 3 agents, where 2 must somehow coincide to live on one box, but it's kind of removing that nice additional safety net of an arbitrary machine failing. Your 2 machine box will keep serving data and foxx apps as long as it is the box with the single agent, which fails. If the other one fails, the system will cease to operate until such time that the other 2 agents are back. 
Having said that, this is how you do it on 2 machines:

1. Redesign you collections with sharding in mind.
2. Backup your database.
3. Setup the new cluster.
4. Implement your design from 1.
5. Restore your data and apps into your cluster.

The step 3 is the one you are mostly interested here. You will need a configuration file for 3 agents, 2 coordinators and 2 db servers. Should you want to move to 3 boxes, You would obviously increase the numbers of db servers and coordinators accordingly. The configuration files would indicate to dedicated database directories for the 7 services; 4 on one machine and 3 on the other.

You would need to startup all 4 services on the one and 3 services on the other machine at boot time. For details on the configuration files, check out the community slack channel for clustering arangodb.